# Microsoft Speech Recognition passive mode?

Tags: speech-recognition

All the examples using Microsoft Speech Recognition that I've found include a Start Button and an End Button to start and stop the listening process. The application I'm working on needs to be constantly listening for a single word to be said. Is there a way to have it always on and listening? I tried Google and couldn't find anything. Thanks.

Comment: Go into the exmaples you see and have the Start Button Event run on application start instead. Likewise have the End button event run on application close.....?

Comment: @gbtimmon When I try this, it only recognizes one word. After that, it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Nevermind I got it to work. I was being stupid -_-. Thanks for your help.